# Why does the average only output the sum and then add the same value for 8th input and when there is only 7 entries

Tags: c#

I am just trying to output the average of a case entry form. The case entry form is suppose to take only 7 inputs and convert it to a double and output the average of all the inputs but my average is not working. I am not too sure. Every time I try to use sum += userInput; and then move onto the if statement which calculates the average, it only outputs either all the numbers added together or some arbitrary number.  I have tried just using the number 7 instead of the MaxDays constant which is 7. I am suppose to output the average to the user in a label. I have asked colleagues and look at reddit, youtube videos, other questions related to this issue but it does not really pertain to my issue.

Here is the code.
private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool isValid;
isValid = ValidateInfections();

```
        double userInput;
        if (double.TryParse(textBoxCaseEntry.Text, out userInput))
        {

           using TryParse.
            if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <= int.MaxValue)
            {

                listBoxCases.Items.Add(textBoxCaseEntry.Text);
                labelDay.Text = "Day " + (listBoxCases.Items.Count + 1);

                for (int p = 0; p <= MaxDays; p++)
                {
                    sum += userInput;
                    if (listBoxCases.Items.Count == MaxDays)
                    {
                        
                        double dailyAverage = sum / MaxDays ;
                        labelAverageDailyCases.Text = "The daily case average is " + dailyAverage.ToString();
                        textBoxCaseEntry.Enabled = false;
                        Enter.Enabled = false;

                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }


        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Calculations can not be performed as one or more validations have failed");
            SetDefaults();
        }
    }
```

Comment: add line `sum = 0;` before `sum += userInput;`. what you are doing in your code based on that logic will work simply by doing `dailyAverage = userInput`, there is no need to calculate the average explicitly. But I think you have been given a `sum` already and then you want to add `userInput` to it and then want to calculate the average? if yes then simply do `sum += userInput;` and then `dailyAverage = sum / MaxDays`. there is no need of `for` loop in this case

Comment: It seems you're adding up userInput as many times as Maxdays, if `userInput = 2` and `MaxDays = 2` then `sum = 6` at the end (by instantiating p to 0 and running until p <= MaxDays you're iterating one more time than MaxDays). Also, listBoxCases never changes during the cycle thus if it's different the first pass, it'll always be different, that's not necessarily bad but I wonder if that's what you expect. Finally, with you statement that `all numbers are just added together`, are you sure `sum` is also a numeric value?